# PHP displaying a certain amount of records per div

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Alright, so I am currently working on a website and for a section of the website I am trying to display some data from an SQL database. And I want the data to display in a such a way as seen here:

```
      <div class="project-list">
                    <ul>
                     <?php
                    try {

                        $stmt = $db->query('SELECT movieID, movieName, movieDesc, movieYear FROM latest ORDER BY movieID DESC');
                        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                                    echo '<li>';
                                        echo '<a href="#" class="no-underline">';
                                        echo '<div class="project">';
                                            echo '<h2 class="project-date">'.$row['movieYear'].'</h2>';
                                            echo '<div class="poster"><img src="assets/img/FoTD_Poster.png" width="160" height="188"></div>';
                                            echo '<h2 class="project-title" align="center"><b>'.$row['movieName'].'</b></h2>';
                                            echo '</a>';
                                        echo '</div>';
                                    echo '</li>';
                                    echo '<li>';
                        }

                    } catch(PDOException $e) {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                    }
                ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Essentially this is supposed to display a record, and it does however, my issue is that the way my style sheet is setup is it will only allow for three project divs to display per project-list/row. And I can't quite figure out how to make it so I can only display 3 records per this div and reset with PHP.

Comment: So the question is about CSS, not PHP, correct? It would help to post relevant stylesheet excerpt.

Comment: The question is mainly about PHP, I more so mentioned CSS in there

Comment: inside the while condition,
you need to check how many products already displayed
you can use if else condition to check,
and create a counter the counts the number of production already displayed

Comment: Okay I sort of understand, but I'm having trouble getting that to work.

Comment: Just do it with [`array_chunk()`](http://www.php.net/array_chunk). Then you get an array with the arrays of chunks (which you'd set to 3) and you could loop effectively.

Comment: Alright, and how would I parse the SQL info into that array_chunck(), I am fairly new to PHP, so I am learning as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, you want to limit the amount of divs to 3 with PHP. Try adding a `LIMIT 3` to your SQL-query:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT movieID, movieName, movieDesc, movieYear FROM latest ORDER BY movieID DESC LIMIT 3');
```

I also noticed that there is one `echo '<li>';` out of place near the end of your while loop. This may or may not be a problem but I would just delete this if there is not need for it.

**Edit: May I have another try?**

If I got you right this time, you want PHP to generate any number of `<div class="project-list">` with a maximum of 3 `<li>` inside each of them, right?

Here you go:

```
<?php
try {
    // this line is for my local setup, you have to change or remove it:
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stackmovies;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT movieID, movieName, movieDesc, movieYear FROM latest ORDER BY movieID DESC');
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo "\n"; // for debugging
        if ($i % 3 == 0) {
            echo '<div class="project-list">';
            echo '<ul>';
        }
        echo "\n"; // for debugging
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="#" class="no-underline">';
        echo '<div class="project">';
        echo '<h2 class="project-date">'.$row['movieYear'].'</h2>';
        echo '<div class="poster"><img src="assets/img/FoTD_Poster.png" width="160" height="188"></div>';
        echo '<h2 class="project-title" align="center"><b>'.$row['movieName'].'</b></h2>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</li>';
        echo "\n"; // for debugging
        if ($i % 3 == 2) {
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo "\n"; // for debugging
        $i++;
    }
    if ($i > 0 && ($i - 1) % 3 != 2) {
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: No that isn't what he wants, he can only print 3 divs per row so he wants to limit the data to 3 items each. Not 3 in total.

Comment: I actually added that echo '<li>'; by accident. But thanks to all of you for your help. And it's sort of like that, but I want to limit the data fetched to 3 per div.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you want to do it. Harnessing [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk). You'll need to add all the data from your sql into an array (Which we will call `$data` in this example).

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Next up, we'll chunk the data up into arrays of 3.

```
$chunked = array_chunk($data, 3);
```

And then all you need to do is harness 2 `foreach()` loops to print it out as you require.

```
// start the loop of chunks
foreach($chunked as $chunk) {
    // you'd open the row here
    // get the items in the specific chunk
    foreach($chunk as $item) {
        // you'd find your data elements in $item 
    }
    // you'd close the row off here
}
```

And here is a working [**`Example`**](https://eval.in/282144).

Comment: @Flakenstine Did it answer your question as to how you should do this? If not, let me know and I'll amend some more !

Comment: All of the answers giving to me were helpful!